# How to display percentages in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have the following code snippet and want to display the values as percentages

```
example .3.342  as 3.34 %
         8.432  as 8.43 %
```

Here is my code snippet

```
   { name: 'eRatio', label: 'eRatio',width: 75, sorttype: 'number', align: "right", formatter: 'percentage', formatoptions: { prefix: "", suffix: " "}  },
```

What do i need to add to display as a percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid has no predefined `formatter: 'percentage'`, but one can use [formatter: "currency"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types):

```
formatter: "currency", formatoptions: { suffix: " %"}
```

The default value of `decimalPlaces` property of `formatoptions` is already 2 like you want. Thus the input values `3.342` and `8.432` will be displayed as `3.34 %` and `8.43 %`.